# как отсылать периодические запросы на сервер ajax

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Есть идея отсылать периодичные запросы на сервер для обновления контента, начал изучать angularjs, но не знаю как реализовать оптимальное решение. Задача в том что бы после загрузки страницы отсылать ajax запросы на сервер с определенной периодичностью, что-бы обновлять контент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну самое простое - это

```
// Каждые 10 секунд
setInterval(function(){
    alert('Ping');
}, 10000);
```

Но я бы рекомендовал смотреть в сторону Websockets и реализацию через [socket.io](http://socket.io/). Не нужно будет вообще выполнять периодические запросы, обо всём может уведомлять сервер.

Comment: Websocket и php - тот еще геморрой. Если в этом нет необходимости,то проще уж периодически отсылать ajax

Comment: Зря вы так думаете. Посмотрите на socket.io - все очень и очень просто. К тому же, все идёт именно в их направлении. Да и нагрузка и на сервер, и на клиента на порядки ниже.

Comment: Я уже давно на nodejs) Там то как раз с сокетами все шикарно

Comment: @Darth вот именно. А если сразу взяться писать на Sails.js, то вообще всё работает из коробки.

Comment: Ну и в общем да, соглашусь с тем, что с PHP сложнее связать сокеты, но уже есть полноценные решения типа [http://socketo.me/](http://socketo.me/) и для PHP, так что имеет смысл двигаться в их направлении